# Can Someone Help in Formula and Validation Rule

Tags: formula, validation

I have some fields on Account Object.

**Fields**-**DataType**

Count__c-Number

Count1__c-Currency

Count2__c-Number

Final_Count__c-Formula

in the Final Count I used a Formula

```
Count1__c / Count__c  / 1000 *  Count2__c
```

The Requirement is if I putt 0 (zero) in count therefore Final Count Should not be null.

Like in image shown there will be value of Count1 and Count2 If I put 1 or any number that should Count and value get printed in Final Count. Means 0 (Zero) we have to ignore if we put zero in Count__c and Count2__c. Is it possible to do Like this by any Condition check.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can check whether the mentioned fields `count1__c`, `Count__c`, `count2__c` fields are having value more then `0`, if yes, please proceed the formula value. if not, update it's as zero.

```
IF (Count1__c > 0 && Count__c > 0 &&  Count2__c > 0) {

    ((Count1__c / Count__c) / (1000 * Count2__c)), //true condition
    0 // False condition
}
```

And you don't need validation for this due to the final count will be update formula answer or zero based on above formula.

Please let me know if it helps.

Thanks.